# Best vent size for replacing drop-ceiling register with boot for drywall using 8" duct?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, vent

[image]

I'm replacing my drop-ceiling with drywall in a basement room. Right now there is one register on an 8" duct – the kind where the duct is just open and passes through a perforated 2'x2' grille into the room. I'm trying to figure out what size register I need to replace it with for best air flow (not reducing or increasing resistance). 4x12 or 6x10 or something else?
Many thanks.

Comment: Pictures are worth a thousand words. I can't see why not keep the duct and paint it white?

Comment: Is this a supply or return duct?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I should've mentioned that this is 8" flex supply duct I'll be adding a 90 degree boot to.

Answer (score 0):

Vents are best as big as possible. It is easy to reduce the flow of a vent, but difficult to increase it.

An 8" round = 4x4x3=36 square inches for air to flow through.

A 4x12 square = 4x12=48 square inches for air to flow through.

A 6x10 square = 6x10=60 square inches for air to flow through.

A square duct does not pass quite as much air as a round duct. Therefore, the 4x12 should work well, but the cornering of square duct does not allow air like the bends of a round duck. If you can fit the 6x10, that will assure enough air.

If you install the 6x10 and you think it gives to much air, then close it off until you are happy. If you install the 4x12 with extra bends and you think it does not give enough air, then life just got rough.

**Answer:** *Follow your heart.*